# "Plugin does not have a valid header" error message on local server

Tags: wordpress

I'm currently working with my first WordPress website using my localhost. While installing a plugin, an error occurred: it says "the plugin does not have a valid header". I tried searching all fixes.

- upload using filezilla
- upload zip file
- tried editing plugin.php file

Any suggestions?

Comment: Which plugin is that? Probably it is not your mistake, but the plugin's

Comment: Which plugin you are used ?

Comment: Hello Guys, i used Facebook Widget, MailChimp for WordPress and Imsanity. But i can't install any of them. i used photography theme, it's weird because the pre installed plug in is not installed on its status. help please

Comment: Hello Guys, @Ashkar, i used Facebook Widget, MailChimp for WordPress and Imsanity. But i can't install any of them. i used photography theme, it's weird because the pre installed plug in is not installed on its status. help please

Comment: Hello Guys, @ManojSrivastava i used Facebook Widget, MailChimp for WordPress and Imsanity. But i can't install any of them. i used photography theme, it's weird because the pre installed plug in is not installed on its status. help please

Comment: Can you just remove all plugins from your plugin folder and copy anywhere then try , i think there is no error in your plugins error is in somewhere else.

Comment: Hi @ManojSrivastava i tried removing all plugins but it still occur, i'm so frustrated with this :(

Comment: Yeah it means there is an error in your code. This error belongs to space , means there is an space left that`s why header already sent error showing. Can you please check your code. Please check your functions.php as well.

Comment: Thank you @ManojSrivastava where can i check this error? is it on plugins.php?

Comment: No , your theme in which you are working. You can check in recent files that you have changed . Just check upper php tag closed and open may be there was space then just remove that.